# need a sql to get the tourist who paid maximum amount in single booking

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

i have two tables tourist(touristid,touristname,city),
bookings(bookingid,touristid,bookingamount)

i need the touristid,touristname,city of tourist who have paid the maximum amount in a single booking

Answer (score 0):

```
/* try this it will work */
select * from tourist 

create table tourist (touristid int,touristname varchar(100),city varchar(10))

insert into tourist values (1,'Rajini','warangal'),(2,'magi','hyderabad'),(3,'srikanth','kamam'),(4,'A','hyderabad')

create table bookings(bookingid int,touristid int ,bookingamount int )

insert into bookings values (101,1,199),(102,4,1000),(103,1,299),(104,2,399)

select * from tourist
select * from bookings


select a.touristid,a.touristname,a.city,b.bookingamount  as amount
 from tourist a join  bookings b on a.touristid=b.touristid
 and b.bookingamount =(select max(bookingamount) from bookings )
```